# Why my image is not showing in my Git-Hub pages?

Tags: html, css

Today I made my First Webpage which is hosted in Github on github pages but I couldn't see the image on my website which is hosted but it is seen in my local machine.
Anyone can help me out with this.

Website Link: https://mustafa2911.github.io/MyFirstWebsite/

Repository Link: https://github.com/Mustafa2911/MyFirstWebsite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it was solved I thing GitHub img src location is case sensitive but in local machine i wasn't a problem